# Shared behavior state across custom elements

Tags: javascript, internationalization, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have these two custom Polymer Elements ([Polymer 1.0.3](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)):

1. Displays text to be translated.
2. Displays button to trigger loading of translation.

I also have a [Behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) that holds the translations (json object) and contains all the functions that make translation possible.

This is what I expect to happen:

1. Click the button in Element 2
2. Translations load into the Behavior
3. Language selection is set in the Behavior
4. Text in Element 1 is updated with the translated equivalent

Steps 1 - 3 happen, but 4 doesn't. The text is never updated. I can get it to work if Elements 1 & 2 are combined as the same element, but not if they're separate (any they need to be separate).

*If you're wondering about the "kick" property, it's something I learned from Polymer 0.5. It got things working when the two elements were combined, so I'm thinking it'll be be necessary when the elements are separate.*

Any idea how I can make this happen? I'm open to alternative paradigms.

## Code

This is roughly how my code is laid out. I also made a [plunker with a single-page test case](http://plnkr.co/edit/bjNzoNkSh0rGSxzAD224?p=info).

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="behavior.html">
  <link rel="import" href="element1.html">
  <link rel="import" href="element2.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-element></my-element>
  <another-element></another-element>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Element 1

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <p>{{localize(label, kick)}}</p>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    behaviors: [
      behavior
    ],
    properties: {
      label: {
        type: String,
        value: 'original'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Element 2

```
<dom-module id="another-element">
  <template>
    <button on-click="buttonClicked">load</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'another-element',
    behaviors: [
      behavior
    ],
    buttonClicked: function() {
      this.registerTranslation('en', {
        original: 'changed'
      })
      this.selectLanguage('en');
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Behavior

```
<script>
  var behavior = {
    properties: {
      kick: {
        type: Number,
        value: 0
      },
      language: {
        type: String,
        value: 'fun'
      },
      translations: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return {};
        }
      }
    },
    localize: function(key, i) {
      if (this.translations[this.language] && this.translations[this.language][key]) {
        return this.translations[this.language][key];
      }
      return key;
    },
    registerTranslation: function(translationKey, translationSet) {
      this.translations[translationKey] = translationSet;
    },
    selectLanguage: function(newLanguage) {
      this.language = newLanguage;
      this.set('kick', this.kick + 1);
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, although the notion is to have `behavior` be a conduit for shared data between instances, as written, each instance will have it's own copy of the `translations` object and the `kick` property.

Second, even if that data was privatized so it could be shared, the `kick` binding made via `localize(label, kick)` is in a different scope from the expression that modifies `kick` (i.e. `this.set('kick', this.kick + 1);` [{sic} this could simply be `this.kick++;`]).

To notify N instances of a change in shared data, one must keep track of those instances. A good way to do this is by attaching event listeners. Another way is simply keeping a list.

Here is an example implementation of your design:

```
    <script>
      (function() {
        var instances = [];
        var translationDb = {};
        var language = '';

        window.behavior = {
          properties: {
            l10n: {
              value: 0
            }  
          },
          attached: function() {
            instances.push(this);
          },
          detached: function() {
            this.arrayDelete(instances, this);
          },
          _broadcast: function() {
            instances.forEach(function(i) {
              i.l10n++;
            });
          },
          localize: function(key, i) {
            if (translationDb[language] && translationDb[language][key]) {
              return translationDb[language][key];
            }
            return key;
          },
          registerTranslation: function(translationKey, translationSet) {
            translationDb[translationKey] = translationSet;
          },
          selectLanguage: function(newLanguage) {
            language = newLanguage;
            this._broadcast();
          }
        };
      })();
  </script>

  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <p>{{localize(label, l10n)}}</p>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        behaviors: [
          behavior
        ],
        properties: {
          label: {
            type: String,
            value: 'original'
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="another-element">
    <template>
      <button on-tap="buttonClicked">load</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        behaviors: [
          behavior
        ],
        buttonClicked: function() {
          this.registerTranslation('en', {
            original: 'changed'
          });
          this.selectLanguage('en');
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```